# C# Changing a generic Class to a subclass

Tags: c#, generics, type-conversion

I am currently trying to change a superclass into one of its subclasses using generics with no success.  Should I just change the interface into a class again and use a super class. I have no Idea on how to do this.

```
public static Boolean AddorUpdateItem<T>(int id, String database, ref T item) where T : Item
{
    if(typeof(T) == typeof(Person)){

        if (ReturnItem(id, database) == null)
        {
            ChangeType(Item item, Person person);
            Person person = new Converter<Item, Person>(item);
            return PersonOperations.AddPerson(item);
        }
        else
        {
            return PersonOperations.UpdatePerson(id, item);
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Item Class

```
public class Item
{

public string Name{
        get;
        set;
}

public int ID{
        get;
        set;
}

}
```

Person Class

```
public class Person : Item
{

    private int reward_point;

    public String FName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    //More variables below.
```

I want this item type to be turned into a person type so that the .addPerson or .updatePerson methods can accept the class.  Or to put it in another words, I want the addorupdate method to accept a single objects that are the subclass of the Item superclass.  Following that it will attempt to determine it's type and send the object to a different method that is designed around that object.

Comment: why don't you add a abstract method update() into Item, which is overwritten  by all subclasses where all the subclass-specific stuff will happen?

Comment: Please don't do this. This super-class will do more than needed. It will mutate to a [God-Object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object). Please also avoid static classes like `PersonOperations`. Please consider using the repository pattern. You can find a good blog post [here](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3107186/how-to-implement-the-repository-design-pattern-in-c.html). Try to keep your classes as simple as you can.

Comment: @sergej The person class only holds variables, and it along with several other classes that I will be building will be a subclass of the Item Super Class.

Comment: @MichaelFeldmeier The Person class only holds the variables I need, as a result there is not much in terms of methods inside the person class.

Comment: well, then maybe you should change that

Comment: As the `Person` class is a model class, it must hold only variables (or Properties). There should not be any logic inside these model classes. The only logic should be inside the `PersonRepository` class and it shouldn't be static.

Answer (score 1):

I really don't like your approach but you can just cast object if you have already checked type.

```
if(typeof(T) == typeof(Person))
{
     Person person = (Person) item;
```

Comment: I will be trying that after I fix some extra issues when it comes to DBdatasets.